# How to Access the Order ID in the New Section on the My Account Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

Customers must confirm a contract for each order when purchasing products. Customers cannot purchase the product without confirming this agreement.

I created a checkbox for this on the checkout page. After customers confirm this, they buy the product. I save the approved contracts to the database. I can find it with the order number. So far, no problem.

On the My Account page, I created a new section (eg orders): Contracts.
From here, every customer can access the contracts. However, I cannot access the contracts from this section that I have created. Because I can't get the order id.

Can I reach the order number with the current user id? I couldn't find any results for this. Or is there a different way?

```
<?php
class WooContractMyAccount
{ 
 private $MyAccountContractsEndPoint = 'registered-contracts ';
    public function __construct()
    {   
    add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items', array($this, 'MyAccountRegistredContracts'), 10, 1);
    add_action('woocommerce_account_' . $this->MyAccountContractsEndPoint . '_endpoint', array($this, 'MyAccountRegistredContractsEndPoint'), 10, 1);
    add_action('init', array($this, 'WooContractInit'));
    }
  
    public function MyAccountRegistredContracts($items)
    {
        $items = array($this->MyAccountContractsEndPoint => __('Registered Contracts')) + $items;
        return $items;
    }



    public function WooContractInit()
    {

        add_rewrite_endpoint($this->MyAccountContractsEndPoint, EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES);
    }
  
}


  public function MyAccountRegistredContractsEndPoint()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'registered_contracts';
        $table_contracts = $wpdb->prefix . 'contracts';
        
        ////The problem is here! ($contracts)
        
        $contracts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT contracts.name,registeredcontracts.date,registeredcontracts.file FROM $table registeredcontracts
            left join $table_contracts contracts ON contracts.id=registeredcontracts.contracts WHERE ref = %d", _______order id must be written_______));
    ?><div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
            <?php if (count($contracts) > 0) : ?>
                <table class="woocommerce-orders-table woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header">
                                <?php _e('Contract') ?>
                            </th>
                            <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header">
                                <?php _e('Date') ?>
                            </th>
                            <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header">
                                <?php _e('File') ?>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($contracts as $contract) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php _e($contract->name); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $contract->date; ?></td>
                                <td><a href="<?php echo CONTRACT_URL . '/' . $contract->file; ?>" target="_blank" class="woocommerce-button button"><?php _e('Download Contract'); ?></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>



                    </tbody>
                </table>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php _e('You do not have a registered contract. ') ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

    <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For questions like this it can be useful to see how it is applied by default in WooCommerce, and base your answer on that

In [/includes/wc-template-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php) on line 3157 - 3186 @version 2.5.0
we find the following:

```php
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_account_orders' ) ) {

    /**
     * My Account > Orders template.
     *
     * @param int $current_page Current page number.
     */
    function woocommerce_account_orders( $current_page ) {
        $current_page    = empty( $current_page ) ? 1 : absint( $current_page );
        $customer_orders = wc_get_orders(
            apply_filters(
                'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query',
                array(
                    'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
                    'page'     => $current_page,
                    'paginate' => true,
                )
            )
        );

        wc_get_template(
            'myaccount/orders.php',
            array(
                'current_page'    => absint( $current_page ),
                'customer_orders' => $customer_orders,
                'has_orders'      => 0 < $customer_orders->total,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

---

As you can see, [wc_get_orders()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) and [get_current_user_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) is used to get the orders for the current customer.

Then the results (`$customer_orders`) are passed to the [myaccount/orders.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/orders.php) template file.

In the template file, a `foreach` is then used to display the orders and the necessary/desired details

```
<?php
foreach ( $customer_orders->orders as $customer_order ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
    // Get order ID
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
```

---

So to answer your question *"Can I reach the order number with the current user id?"*, yes this is possible and is indeed the right way to proceed